# Dangerous Website May Have Infected System?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, malware

Last day I finished my website and tried to check how it looks on other browsers using www.browsershots.org , but I had a mistake while writing the address and I wrote `http://browsershot.com` which redirected me to `http://rudespace.com` . The website which I've been redirected to is an adult one and I really hate I did that.

Now I'm really worried and I don't know what should I do? Stay calm because everything's fine or worry?

Comment: I'd say, stay calm if everything is file, and worry a bit, if not.

Comment: It happens at times. Don't worry, it was never your fault.

Answer (score 3):

Stay calm.

1. Not all adult sites provide you with malware
2. If nothing special happened besides a redirect, there is no reason to suspect misbehaviour.
3. The site is not listed as suspected as far as I checked, for instance with [avg](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/sitereports/domain/rudespace.com/)

You migtht want to remove your browser history or cookies if you hate the fact that you could be 'linked' to an adult site, but that's more of an "*ow no, if someone uses my account and really digs deep, they see this site's address*" thing, and not an "*ow no, there is something wrong with my computer and they are stealing my creditcard*" thing :)

Answer (score 2):

I analysed that page using virustotal.com, [here](https://www.virustotal.com/url/1b126a5c7273ec9567c49f341e9a591ba6f5dabded4f075e6d067f7d3f4acd0a/analysis/1358931678/) are the results.
Furthermore, in general, you don't have to be afraid of viruses when on Linux. You can read [here](http://librenix.com/?inode=21) about this topic, when you are more interested in viruses on Linux.